# Appium framework: Why do I have this error message with 'driver' cannot be resolved. Selenium is installed

Tags: java, automation, frameworks, appium

Hi I am creating an appium framework with testNG and  I was copying a drag n drop android test to use in my framework as a basic example.

For some reason 'driver' has an error message next to it (see below) and I'm confused why I would get that as I have selenium in my pom.xml file ( see below).  I also imported selenium (see below too).  I'm really confused why I have this message.  I am also adding the test case  with this question.

I am wondering:

- Did I forget to import something into my test?
- Did I forget to add  something to my .pom xml file?
- Why would error message appear when
  the test it originates from works perfectly (I created that test
  too)?

[image]

Pom xml file

```
<dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Test

```
package android;



import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Dragndroptest  extends invoke {

             //Given I am on the Home screen 
             //When I  tap Views   
             //Then I will see the View menu 
             //When I am in the 'view menu' I will select 'drag n drop'
             //Then I will see 3 dots  
             //When  I select a dot and drag it
             //Then I will drop it on the dot below


    @BeforeTest
    public void Cookies() throws MalformedURLException
    {

          AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =Capabilities();

        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Views").click();


    }

    @Test
    public void dragnddrop()
    {

        //tap syntax using TOUCHACTIONS
                TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);
                t.tap(driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Drag and Drop")).perform();


                //Drag & Drop Syntax 

                t.longPress(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_1")).
                moveTo(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_3")).release().perform();


    }


    @AfterTest
    public void Testtitle here()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Update:  A friend said I should add the desired capabilities to the test case and that should solve the problem.  I was bit a confused by that because of a framework job is to make things more centralised. How does adding the desired capabilities  in my test case fix my problem?  I am trying understand the logic behind it.

What happens  IF something changes in the 'desired capabilities' I will have to go through every test and modify it.  With potential 100+ automation tests that is not a good idea.  

So my question is this, why is the inheritance class 'extends'  not suitable in testNG?

Answer (score 1):

You must define your AppiumDriver outside of your method. You must define desired capabilities. Using desiredCapabilities, it will know which app to open and in which device we should run it. You must enable appium server defined in your driver.

```
public class Dragndroptest  extends invoke {

    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setupDesiredCaps(){
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Any name");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "your device udid");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "your device platform version");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "your app Package name");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "your app's main package name");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    }

 //your other code after it
 }
```

Comment: So  what you are saying that in  a testNG test class  I need to define my capabilities outside of my method in the  'Before Suite' section so the test will  know which app to run BEFORE actually performing the test.  Is that correct?

Comment: Testng doesn't require desiredCapabilities. DesiredCapabilities is required for appium. To run your app in appium, you need desiredCapability. Since you are testing your app using appium, you first need to start appium and then run your test cases.

Comment: I more question.  How do I find the app package and app activity  for the Android app ApiDemos-debug.apk.  I am testing on an emulator not a device